# SASS not working after OSX upgrade

Tags: sass

I looks like SASS is trying to use the wrong version of ruby after the Yosemite update:

```
$ sass
bash: /usr/bin/sass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure it should be pointing to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/current/...`

Is there a way to update the sass ruby path?

**edit**

```
$sudo gem update sass
```

Has no effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling sass and reinstalling it fixed this

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
sudo gem install sass
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run `sudo gem uninstall sass` (`sass -v` yields the same error).

Running just `sudo gem install sass` is sufficient to update SASS.